# variable substitution in properties file not working in spring boot 1.x and apache camel2.x

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-camel, spring-camel

I have declared one property in the application.properties file like below

```
hu.ednpoint=https://${serverhost.name}/subscription/event
de.ednpoint=https://${serverhost.name}/consume/event
```

I am expecting the value of ${serverhost.name} will be overridden by api.xfjj.com:443 but it's giving the below results
accessing values camel route

```
.log("{{hu.ednpoint}}")
.log("{{de.ednpoint}}")
.to("{{de.ednpoint}}")
.end()
```

Expected results :

```
hu.ednpoint=https://api.xfjj.com:443/subscription/event
de.ednpoint=https://api.xfjj.com:443/consume/event
```

Actual Results :

```
hu.ednpoint=https:/subscription/event
de.ednpoint=https:/consume/event
```

I am not sure where it's going wrong. I am really grateful if anyone could help me to resolve this issue.This issue is occurring in camel2 but in camel3 works fine

Comment: Is that the actual endresult or something you typed out yourself from memory? Because in that endresult the double slashes have disappeared, there is more missing than only the variable value.

Comment: yes it's end results // double slashes also missing

Comment: Well then the problem is not with the serverhost.name property. Is Maven involved in this project? If so, is it configured to do resource filtering by any chance?

Comment: How are you checking the actual results? I mean how and where are you fetching those properties?

Comment: Just tried to verify this "problem" and tried to check the result (with SB 2, not 1, but maybe in this case this is irrelevant): If I package the application (with maven) and look for the "substituted" `application.properties` (in the packaged jar), the variable is not substituted and the value is equal to the source `application.properties`. But if I write some (rest)controller, load the value with `@Value("${de.endpoint}") String deEndpoint` and print it to the console, the variable is substituted.

Comment: @hjoeren I guess that is expected behaviour. If you are using maven variables `@..@` then only they will be substituted at the time of build. Otherwise Spring placeholders `${...}` are substituted at the runtime only. It is well documented here - https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.M3/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html#howto-discover-build-in-options-for-external-properties

Comment: @JigneshM.Khatri Not sure if the question is about maven variables, because in the question it's given `serverhost.name=api.xfjj.com:443`. So I think the question is like "how can I use property `X` in the property `Y`, both are defined in `application.properties`".

Comment: @hjoeren Yeah I know that, I was just giving the explanation of your comment (you said that property was not replaced in Jar). As you said that it is working runtime, so I agree with you. It will work runtime without any issues. But need to get it clarified from OP that how and where properties are being accessed.

Comment: I am accessing in one customized spring class like below ```   @Component
class Customer{

@value("${de.endpoint}")
String hostName;

somemethd(){
System.out.println(hostName);
}
}```

Comment: Just tried to reproduce with Spring Boot 1.5.22.RELEASE, but I'm not able to do so (https://gitlab.com/hjoeren/variable-substitution-sb1): The variable is resolved substituted. Can you tell us which version you are using?

Comment: The question seems to have an issue itself. actually, When i am accessing with @Value it's working fine but when I am accessing the value in camel route it's not working, now I need to edit the question properly

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try using yaml instead of properties file.
Eg.

```
apiConfig:
    pf:
      host:
        name: api.xfjj.com:443
      uri:
        base:
          admin: https://${apiConfig.pf.host.name}/
        apis:
          orders:
            get:
              subscription: ${apiConfig.pf.uri.base.admin}/suscription/event/
              consume:${apiConfig.pf.uri.base.admin}/consume/event/
```

Comment: I can't do that as the application is monolithic and it has application.properties file

Comment: in that case can you make `serverhost.name` a environment variable than a property in property in the Property file.